# SOQL query issue within a for loop - UnexpectedToken

Tags: apex, soql

I have an issue with my Apex Code but I have no idea how to solve it ..

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<string,integer> ApprovalKPI(){
        Map<string, integer> dataExportmap = new map<string, integer>();
        for(Region__c RegionItem:[SELECT Id, Name FROM Region__c]){

            List <Approval__c> Total_data = [SELECT Id,Status__c, Date__c, Approval_Date__c, Opportunity__c, 
                                             Type__c, Opportunity__r.Country__c, Opportunity__r.Region__c  
                                            FROM Approval__c
                                            WHERE Opportunity__r.Region__c = RegionItem.Name];
            dataExportmap.put(RegionItem.Name, Total_data.size())
        }
        
        System.debug(dataExportmap);
        return dataExportmap;
        
        
    }
```

However I get an Apex code error Unexpected token 'RegionItem.Name'.
If I replace in my code `WHERE Opportunity__r.Region__c = RegionItem.Name];`
by
`WHERE Opportunity__r.Region__c = 'Europe'];` it work great .. could someone explain me what is the issue is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using variables in queries, you need to use colon `:` before the variable name. [This](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/use-bind-variables-and-aggregate-functions) trailhead can give you more details.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<string,integer> ApprovalKPI(){
        Map<string, integer> dataExportmap = new map<string, integer>();
        for(Region__c RegionItem:[SELECT Id, Name FROM Region__c]){

            List <Approval__c> Total_data = [SELECT Id,Status__c, Date__c, Approval_Date__c, Opportunity__c, 
                                             Type__c, Opportunity__r.Country__c, Opportunity__r.Region__c  
                                            FROM Approval__c
                                            WHERE Opportunity__r.Region__c =: RegionItem.Name];
            dataExportmap.put(RegionItem.Name, Total_data.size())
        }
        
        System.debug(dataExportmap);
        return dataExportmap;
        
        
    }
```